# MySQL Assign Return Value to Variable

Tags: mysql

How do you declare variable and set a value which is a return from a query on them later.

Sample Stored Procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sampledb`.`SetVariableEx`()

    BEGIN

        -- declare variable
        DECLARE xVarA INT;                
        DECLARE xVarB INT;      

        -- in this line, i would like to set a value on xVarA which is a COUNT
        -- of record from table SINGLETABLE
        -- i am getting error on this line.
        SELECT xVarA := COUNT(*) FROM SingleTable;

        -- the value of xVarA is added by 1 and set it to xVarB
        SET xVarB = xVarA + 1;

        -- insert the value of xVarB to the table SINGLETABLE
        INSERT INTO SingleTable(SingleColumn) VALUES (xVarB);

        -- lastly, display all records.
        SELECT * FROM SingleTable;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

how would i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SET xVarA := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SingleTable);
```

However, for this example, have you considered [using an auto auto-incrementing value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html), rather than managing the value yourself?

Comment: AutoIncrement is not my point in the qestion but rather setting the value from the query to a variable. SET xVarA := SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SingleTable; does not work but by putting the query inside a Parenthesis works. SET xVarA := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SingleTable);  thanks!

Comment: @491243 Somehow missed this previously, rather belatedly got round to updating my answer. Thanks.